# How to append each object to its respective 'block' of elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
var clubbingLocations = $('#clubbing-locations');

$.getJSON("/js/location.json", function(data) { //load json

    for (var i = 1; i <= data.locations.length; i++){ //loop through json, append html and objects
        clubbingLocations.append("<div class='night-type location'>" + 
        "<a href='location.html'>" +
        "<div class='overlay'>" +
        "<div class='overlay'>" +
        "<span class='fav checked glyphicon glyphicon-heart' aria-hidden='true'></span>" +
        "<h4>" + data.locations[i].name + "</h4>" +
        "<div class='rating-hold'>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</a>" +
        "</div>"
        );
        for (var j = 1; j <= data.locations[i].rating; j++){
            $('.rating-hold').append("<span class='filled glyphicon glyphicon-star' aria-hidden='true'></span>");
        }
    }
```

I am trying to append the object's review to each of its respective `rating-hold`, however, the reviews are accumulating and adding themselves on to each other instead of appending to the respective class, them moving on. 
The first rating inserts its self perfectly, but after that they start adding themselves onto each other.

Comment: Can you share your `HTML` please?

Comment: @Tha'erAl-Ajlouni I just have a div with an id of 'clubbing-locations' which im appending the html and objects too.

Comment: check my answer below, I done what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a jQuery object with your html string first.

Then you can search within that object to find the current `rating-hold` and append icons to it.

Finally, append the whole object including the icons to `clubbingLocations`

```
for (var i = 0; i <= data.locations.length - 1; i++){ //loop through json, append html and objects
    // create jQuery object
    var $nightType= $("<div class='night-type location'>" + 
        "<a href='location.html'>" +
        "<div class='overlay'>" +
        "<div class='overlay'>" +
        "<span class='fav checked glyphicon glyphicon-heart' aria-hidden='true'></span>" +
        "<h4>" + data.locations[i].name + "</h4>" +
        "<div class='rating-hold'>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</a>" +
        "</div>"
        );


        for (var j = 0; j <= data.locations[i].rating; j++){
            // append icons to object created above
            $nightType.find('.rating-hold').append("<span class='filled glyphicon glyphicon-star' aria-hidden='true'></span>");
        }
         // append object to dom
         clubbingLocations.append($nightType);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, ill definitely keep this in mind for the future

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery .each [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

```
$('.rating-hold').each(function(index){
    $(this).append('html code here');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are appending using the `.rating-hold` alone, which will append all to the first `location`, try giving locations ids, and assign stars to each separately using this instead:

```
var clubbingLocations = $('#clubbing-locations');

$.getJSON("/js/location.json", function(data) { //load json

for (var i = 0; i <= data.locations.length - 1; i++){ //loop through json, append html and objects
    clubbingLocations.append(
        "<div id='location" + i + "' class='night-type location'>" + 
        "<a href='location.html'>" +
        "<div class='overlay'>" +
        "<div class='overlay'>" +
        "<span class='fav checked glyphicon glyphicon-heart' aria-hidden='true'></span>" +
        "<h4>" + data.locations[i].name + "</h4>" +
        "<div class='rating-hold'>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</a>" +
        "</div>"
    );

    for (var j = 0; j <= data.locations[i].rating; j++){
        $('#location' + i + ' .rating-hold').append("<span class='filled glyphicon glyphicon-star' aria-hidden='true'></span>");
    }
}
```